# Connect to a SQL Server using NodeJS

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, config

I'm having a project which I need the server to have db. I chose Sql Server 2012 (because I used it).
Now the sql configured with a Windows authentication and I unable to connect it (maybe it's because the config string is not good).

Should I use windows authentication or sql connection?
I use require ('mssql') and my config is like this:

```
var config = {
  user: 'MyName',
  password: '123',
  server: 'localhost',
  database: 'MyProj',
  options: {
    instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS'
  }
};
```

**error message:**

> { [ConnectionError: Failed to get response from SQL Server Browser on
>   localhost] name: 'ConnectionError', message: 'Failed to get response
>   from SQL Server Browser on localhost', code: 'EINSTLOOKUP' }

What did I do wrong? (I know something wrong because it doesn't working)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: { [ConnectionError: Failed to get response from SQL Server Browser on localhost]

  name: 'ConnectionError',
  message: 'Failed to get response from SQL Server Browser on localhost',
  code: 'EINSTLOOKUP' }

Comment: Are you running SQL Server on the standard port, 1433?

Comment: Yes I am (I didn't change any parameter in configuration)

Comment: My problem was I needed to add users and I tried to use one created when I install the db, a big mistake of mine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I normally always make sure all my MS SQL Servers are setup in Mixed Mode. Then you can use the actual username and password in your connection string

Comment: Agreed.  I don't know the mssql module but I would guess it's not doing ntlm/integrated auth.

Comment: I configured MSSQL when installed it as a mixed and inserted my password (and confirmation) but now I can connect sql management only using windows authentication, SQL authentication doesn't work.